# Dockerized Python Project - Best way to manage dependencies: Dockerfile or requirements.txt

Tags: python, docker, pip, dependency-management

What is the best practice for handling dependencies of a dockerized python project? Would I declare all of them in the Dockerfile or in the requirements.txt?

Comment: Dockerfile is not a way to maintain python dependencies

Comment: If you have a `requirements.txt` (or `Pipfile`) you can use it in a normal Python environment, or in Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file, then install them with Docker:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle the dependencies is using `requirements.txt`

Try this dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
COPY . /work
WORKDIR /work
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```